# Bug z-index IE - Marcador de leitura [input] sobrepondo menu dropdown

Tags: internet-explorer, input, dropdown, z-index

[image: Marcador de leitura sobrepondo menu dropdown]

Alguém já teve esse problema no IE?

Tenho um menu e logo abaixo um campo input. Quando seleciono o campo input e aparece o marcador de leitura, ele sobrepõe o dropdown do menu.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste o código pro pessoal dar uma olhada...